# POST request with filled form values to login

Tags: http, authentication, http-headers

I don't use javascript, so I'm completely new to it.

I have a [link](http://www.sudoku-knacker.de/anmeldung.htm?ref=dailyfield) where I want to login per POST request. Just send a POST request with pre-defined correct login and password and get the data on the next page.

I'm using developer mode in Chrome to look on the requests sent by browser. 
But when I type in correct combination of username and password, I don't see a single POST request, only GETs.

With incorrect username and password I'm able to see a POST request with following **Form Data** values:

```
xjxfun:_validateLogin
xjxr:1389197444586
xjxargs[]:<xjxobj>
    <e><k>Username</k><v>SmyUsername</v></e>
    <e><k>Password</k><v>SmyPassword</v></e>
    <e><k>Autologin</k><v>S1</v></e>
    <e><k>REFERER</k><v>Sdailyfield</v></e>
</xjxobj>
```

Here I typed in `myUsername` for **Username** and `myPassword` for **Password**.

### My question is

**What POST request do I need to send to this server to imitate form filling and submitting?**

Thank you for answering. The best answer you can give is to describe the POST request with necessary data/headers/values, so that I can prove it fast in some REST client in browser

Comment: Show your code, it's better.

Comment: I have no code, first I'm trying to send manual POST requests from a Rest Client App in Chrome to see if it works

Comment: If you don't get Chrome to show you the magic try Wireshark instant. It *will* show you the request if there is one.

Comment: Use POSTMAN extension in chrome, it's better to try POST and GET in forms.

Comment: You can disable javascript and see if you can still login. If you can, you can simply check the form that's there and post to the same page.

Comment: @jeroen Without javascript authentication doesn't work.

Comment: @Kimmax Thanks, I see the request now, but I'm somehow not able to replicate it

Comment: Show the js code sendig the request and lelated form fields.

Comment: @Fanda I don't use javascript, sorry for being unclear, fixed this in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the data I got sent from a valid login:

```
xjxfun:_validateLogin
xjxr:1389422948740
xjxargs[]:<xjxobj><e><k>Username</k><v>S<![CDATA[myemailhere]]></v></e><e><k>Password</k><v>Smypasswordhere</v></e><e><k>Autologin</k><v>S1</v></e><e><k>REFERER</k><v>Sdailyfield</v></e></xjxobj>
```

And this is what I got returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><xjx><cmd cmd="js">Slocation.href = 'sudoku_des_tages.htm';</cmd></xjx>
```

By the way, this was a POST request.

I think the reason that you can only see GET requests, was because an HTTP redirect occurred on the server-side with your authentication details, and that request (as with all page requests) is a GET request, which is probably why you can only see GET requests with successful authentication.

**Update:** From what I understand, you are sending the values as header values (in others words, alongside `Content-Type` and the like), while you should send them in the post formdata. This is why you are finding your answer.

Comment: I try to send a POST request with headers xjxfun, xjxr, xjxargs[] and relative data and I get error on setting xjxargs[] header. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @BogdanWeidmann Nothing wrong. It's just you're not receiving any response data for some reason, which isn't your fault - the server just isn't sending anything.

Comment: Are you sure? Advanced Rest Client, which I'm using cannot even **send** the request. Not that server responded something

Comment: @BogdanWeidmann You should post it to `http://www.sudoku-knacker.de/anmeldung.htm?ref=dailyfield`. Is that what you did?

Comment: @BogdanWeidmann Well, mine could be sent. Did you set it as type `POST`?

Comment: My mistake was that I added header values and to make it work I had to set everything as payload values. Thank you!

Comment: @BogdanWeidmann No worries. I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45045/discussion-between-bogdan-weidmann-and-think123)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use CURL :

```
    $fields_string = '';
    $url = "yourProceesfileURL";
    $userdata = array(
        'email' => youremail,
        'password' => yourpassword
    );
    foreach ($userdata as $key => $value) {
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($userdata));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This solution was suggested when the question was tagged with JavaScript and PHP and without Objective-C.

You can use JQuery to simulate the form filling like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#Username').val('MyUsername');
    $('#Password').val('MyPassword');
    $('input[type=submit]').trigger("click");
});
```

**[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cuq2S/)**

First you want to set the values by getting the input element with his id and then setting his value. Once you finish updating all the requested values just trigger the submit button.

This will simulate you filling the form and submitting it. To do this automatically I would use PHP to get the content of the page and then firing the JQuery function:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://www.sudoku-knacker.de/anmeldung.htm?ref=dailyfield");
```

Comment: I'm programming in Objective C. How can I use JQuery there? 
I thought, you can actually simulate form filling using simple HTTP protocol (POST request with right headers). Is it actually possible?

Comment: @BogdanWeidmann you tagged your question with JavaScript and PHP but not with Objective C.